# Need html 5 color picker with limited color shades

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, color-picker, color-shade

I need a html/jquery based color picker, which have option for show color range of one shades, Like green and its shades, red and its shades. If any jquery plugin available for this. More better if it follow html5 / bootstrap.  Their are online shades/tilt generator tool like in (http://colllor.com/ ) . But I need to use as library to show on my page.

UPDATE : I only need to support FF & Chrome latest versions, So latest technologies like HTML5 is ok for me. However it must show only one color palette ( Like green all its shades & tilt for instance ).

UPDATE 2 : I have another option to manually create a color palette. I did found a library to get shades/tilt for a color. https://github.com/bgrins/TinyColor .  But this would be last option for me if no plugin found.

Comment: `<input type="color"/>`, why to go jQuery then?

Comment: IE does not support it, enough said. The question is off-topic though.

Comment: @meskobalazs, He is asking HTML5, why would he need to worry about IE?

Comment: Well, IE does support HTML5 (albeit quite poorly) and too many people use it to ignore (I wish it could be ignored)

Comment: @meskobalazs I do not need to support IE and its versions. Only to support FF & Chrome latest versions, So HTML 5 is ok with me

Comment: Then you should have said this in the question, then use the color input.

Comment: @Manoz I prefer html 5 color field. But as in my question, I need to show only one color shades/tilt at a time. I do not think html5 color support this.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_colorpicker.asp?colorhex=F0F8FF like this?

Comment: @ctwheels, Yes like this, But if widget is smaller or better horizontal & smaller.

Comment: There are a lot of god plugins out there... [here](http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-color-picker/) is a good overview and [this one](http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-color-picker/full_screen_preview/5946602?ref=jqueryrain&ref=jqueryrain&clickthrough_id=328975948&redirect_back=true) supports what you are searching for.

Comment: @JanHommes I know their are lot of color picker plugins out there. But question is any of plugin have option for show only one color's shades/tilt ? Second plugin do not look like ideal one, also I think it is paid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems no plugin is customized to fulfill my requirement. So I just made my jquery plugin. It is very basic but fulfill my initial requirement.

https://github.com/kuldeep-k/colorShades

Still if more better plugins available. Please suggest.